# Angular template theming

Tags: html, angularjs, templates, themes

Within our application we're trying to achieve (html)templating based on themes. For example, if the specified theme is default, we should use the basic templates, but if the theme is 'coolTheme', all templates postfixed with '-coolTheme.html' should be used instead.

We have considered different solutions, but figured there must be a simple/default way to do this. These are the options we came up with:

1. Gulp task that puts all html files per theme in a {myTheme}-templates.js. When changing the theme angular resets the `$templateCache`, loads in the theme file and puts the templates in the `$templateCache`.
2. Gulp task that copies over all *-.myTheme.html to where the default templates should be (based on given theme parameter). Disadvantages are that you cannot change the theme on the fly.
3. Intercepting/decorating the `$templateRequest`, to check in a list/configuration file if the requested file is marked as 'themed', and then change the request to 'theFile-{myTheme}.html' instead

Which is the best way to handle this? And why? Does anyone have the 'perfect' solution for this?

Comment: Will the templates be different html markup or just different classes?

Comment: Also, what determines the theme? Is it a gulp argument? A global variable? etc.

Comment: Different html markup. It can be a gulp argument, but its also available as a data attribute on the body element (`<body data-theme="myTheme">`)